# Changing property on Carto VL feature?

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-vl

I have a map that relates to a table.  When the user selects a table row, I would like to highlight the corresponding map feature.  This is the only way I found to do it:

```
const siteGeoJSON = SitesToGeoJSON(sites, activeId);
const newSource = new carto.source.GeoJSON(siteGeoJSON);
siteLayer.update(newSource, siteViz);
```

What I'm doing here is regenerating the entire `GeoJSON` object to set a single property indicating whether each feature is active or not, then digesting that into Carto anew.  Features with the active property have a different symbol.

This probably isn't a very efficient way to do this, though.  Is there any way to change feature properties without creating a new source?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer this question, but it solved the problem.  Instead of changing the property, I found a way to change the presentation: I hold on to `siteViz` then iterate through the features contained in `siteViz.variables.visibleFeatures.value` to find the site I want to change, and enlarge it by using `f.width.blendTo(16, 200)` and later `f.width.reset()`.

Comment: If it works, I would say it is a valid answer. So I would suggest posting your answer in more detail and more code snippets (or link to working example).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by holding onto `siteViz` as an upper-scope Javascript variable, initializing it with this:
`@visibleFeatures: viewportFeatures($id)`

When the user hovers on a table row, I use State in React to set an `activeId`, and a corresponding side-effect function (`useEffect`) updates the map:

```
    siteViz.variables.visibleFeatures.value.forEach(f => {
      if (f.properties.id === activeId) {
        f.width.blendTo(16, 200);
      } else {
        f.width.reset();
      }
    });
```